# Two fetchColumns next to each other not working

Tags: php, pdo

I want to fetch two different specific columns and I have already tested this and  it clearly shows that the second fetchColumn doesn't work because I've tried to echo it but it only echoes the first fetchColumn

This is the code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM logins WHERE login_name = :username');
$criteria = ['username' => $_POST['Username']];
$stmt->execute($criteria);
$user = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
$admin = $stmt->fetchColumn(6);
if (password_verify($_POST['Password'], $user) && !empty($admin)) {
    $_SESSION['adminlogin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['adminloginname'] = $_POST['Username'];
    header('location: adminpage.php');
} 
elseif (password_verify($_POST['Password'], $user)) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['Username'];
    header('location: latestarticles.php');
    } else {
        echo '<p> Wrong password </p>';
    }
}
```

I want this code to check if the $admin variable has a value or not, if it does then you get admin rights if not then you get normal user rights. But the $admin = $stmt->fetchColumn(6); doesn't show any results.

UPDATE: One thing that I have just tried was adding another search query beneath the first fetchColumn, it works but surely this can't be the only way, there has to be something easier.
My code looks like this now:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM logins WHERE login_name = :username');
$criteria = ['username' => $_POST['Username']];
$stmt->execute($criteria);
$user = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM logins WHERE login_name = :username');
$criteria = ['username' => $_POST['Username']];
$stmt->execute($criteria);
$admin = $stmt->fetchColumn(6);
if (password_verify($_POST['Password'], $user) && !empty($admin)) {
    $_SESSION['adminlogin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['adminloginname'] = $_POST['Username'];
    header('location: adminpage.php');
} 
 elseif (password_verify($_POST['Password'], $user)) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['Username'];
    header('location: latestarticles.php');
    } else {
        echo '<p> Wrong password </p>';
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that fetchColumn is the only way to fetch in PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php manual says:

> (1) fetchColumn() should not be used to retrieve boolean columns, as it is
>   impossible to distinguish a value of FALSE from there being no more
>   rows to retrieve
>
> (2) There is no way to return another column from the same row if
>   you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

Instead you could do this with fetch() method as shown below:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user = $result['user_column'];
$admin = $result['admin_column'];
```

Here is the PHP manual reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: shit the bed, yeah I read through stuff quickly and just usually look at the actual code which doesn't tell me much, this is perfect thank you @Amila Dev